# Form to select id before passing it to 'new' form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I have some two nested resources, so that a Product can have many Bookings. On one page in a different controller I want to create a new booking and since it's a "general" booking I want a select menu to appear in a modal window where the user is able to pick one of the existing products and then go to the booking page.

How can I do this?

I have no problem setting up the modal and the "New booking" page is already there. What I need is a form that generates a list of existing products, picks the selected product id and then gets /products/:product_id/bookings/new .

To clearify;

I have the two resources set in routes:

```
resources :products do
  resources :bookings
end
```

A product has many bookings, and thus the path to create a new booking will be /products/:product_id/bookings/new.

I have another controller with a view where I want a button for creating a new booking. Problem is I don't know for what product the user wants to create a booking when the "New booking" button is clicked. To solve that my plan was to show a modal window containing a select with all products, that the user should be able to select a product and then be redirected to /products/:product_id/bookings/new with :product_id as selected product.

Right now I have a solution that works but it's not very nice, I have created the form with an action to /products/:product_id/bookings/new and with method = get. Then I catch the submit with JavaScript, change the action and then submits again:

```
$("#new_booking_form").submit(function() { 
    var product_id = $(this).find('select').val();
    var form_action = $(this).attr("action");
    var new_form_action = form_action.replace(/product_id/, product_id);

    $(this).attr("action", new_form_action);
    $(this).submit();
});
```

This solution works but is very ugly! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly and there is a relationship where product has many bookings, you would want something like this is your routes.rb

RAILS 3:

```
resources :products do
  resource :bookings
end
```

RAILS 2:

```
map.resource :products do |product|
  product.resource :bookings
end
```

then direct it to the page using this:

```
format.html { redirect_to new_product_bookings_url(@product) }
```

Comment: I edited my question, hope it makes more sense now! Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can show list of products with links to the creation form instead of select in modal dialog:

```
<ul>
<% Product.all.each do |product| %>
  <li><%= link_to product.name, new_product_bookings_path(product) %></li>
<% end%>
</ul>
```